# static method 'buildBlock' requires that 'Button<Any>.Type' conform to 'View'

Tags: swiftui

New to swiftui.  How do I solve this?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            VStack {
                Text("Hello World")
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            }
            VStack {
                Button(action:  {
                    self.volumeCheck()
                }) {
                    Image("chimes")
                      .renderingMode(Image.TemplateRenderingMode?.init(Image.TemplateRenderingMode.original))

                }
                Button(action: {
                    self.volumeCheck()
                }) {
                    Text("Click chimes to test volume")
                }
            }
        }

    }

    func volumeCheck() {

    }
}
```

**Report**

```
static method 'buildBlock' requires that 'Button<Any>.Type' conform to 'View'

----------------------------------------

failedToBuildDylib: /Users/scottlydon/Library/Autosave Information/SmartWorkTimer/SmartWorkTimer/ContentView.swift:18:20: error: static method 'buildBlock' requires that 'Button<Any>.Type' conform to 'View'
            VStack {
                   ^
SwiftUI.ViewBuilder:3:24: note: where 'C1' = 'Button<Any>.Type'
    public static func buildBlock<C0, C1>(_ c0: C0, _ c1: C1) -> TupleView<(C0, C1)> where C0 : View, C1 : View
                       ^
/Users/scottlydon/Library/Autosave Information/SmartWorkTimer/SmartWorkTimer/ContentView.swift:26:17: error: generic parameter 'Label' could not be inferred
                Button
                ^
/Users/scottlydon/Library/Autosave Information/SmartWorkTimer/SmartWorkTimer/ContentView.swift:26:17: note: explicitly specify the generic arguments to fix this issue
                Button
                ^
                      <<#Label: View#>>
```

Comment: I always build Buttons as `Button(action: {}, label: {})` and I think that you should try it that way too. The error message seems to say that `label` is missing.

Comment: There are no errors when I paste the above code into Xcode, which version are you using?

Comment: same here XCode 11.2.1 -> no error

Answer (score 7):

I've met this same bug (Static method 'buildBlock' requires that 'Button' conform to 'View') with Xcode 13.1. Not with all projects, just with some.
Amazingly what helped me is to use Button the following way (just prefixed with SwiftUI):

SwiftUI.Button

Comment: My project had a conflict with a `Button` defined elsewhere and the use of a SwiftUI `Button`, thus the need to resolve the namespace conflict when using a `SwiftUI.Button`. Renaming the other `Button` removed the need to prefix the `SwiftUI.` for the `Button` in question.

Answer (score 0):

You have to integrate UIKIT in your project and make the UIButton to conform to UIViewRepresentable and UIViewControllerRepresentable let you port existing UIKit components to SwiftUI. One of the simplest examples is UIButton, which at the time of writing doesn’t have a corresponding SwiftUI component.

```
struct ButtonView: UIViewRepresentable {


func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<ButtonView>) -> UIButton {
    return UIButton(frame: sampleFRame)
}

func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIButton, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<ButtonView>) {
    
}

}
```

//Inside swift ui

```
 var body: some View {
    VStack {
        ButtonView().onTapGesture {
                print("Tapped")
        }
        Spacer()
    }
}
```